# Get fetch results with MusixMatch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, cors-anywhere

hope you're doing well
I've have been learning about APIs, how to use them and when to use them, and trying to understand some concepts, but today I'm stuck

I've been trying to use the MusixMatch API, so i went through the documentations, which was kind of self-explanatory but anytime I make a get request with `fetch` to an end point, my results are unusual.

correct me if I'm wrong but a fetch request is a `get` request by default so my functions looks like this

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(
    `https://corsproxylyricallydemo.herokuapp.com/https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/artist.get?artist_id=118&apikey=${ApiKey}`
  )
    .then((res) => console.log("res", res.json()))
    .then((data) => console.log("data", data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, []);
```

I also created a cors proxy to fix the cors error I was getting earlier so the above function is supposed to Get the artist data from their database.
but my results are

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4u7l0.png)

and from what I can understand the res.json might have some issue but I don't know how to solve it, so I went further to just test to see what was the log message of `res` without the `.json()`, and my result showed

```
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://corsproxylyricallydemo.herokuapp.com/https…st_id=118&apikey=${API-KEY}', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...),
bodyUsed: false,
headers: Headers {},
ok: true,
redirected: false,
status: 200,
statusText: "OK",
type: "cors",
url:"https://corsproxylyricallydemo.herokuapp.com/https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/artist.get?artist_id=118&apikey=${API_KEY}",
[[Prototype]] :  Response
```

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjuuW.png)

so I'm getting a status `200` with an empty body,
I am lost, could someone please help me out? and also if it's not too much to ask,please recommend any resource I could read or study to understand these API concepts better
cheers.

Comment: use `res.text()` instead if the result isn't JSON - looks like the response is actually HTML - perhaps read the response (in the browser developer tools) to see what you're actually getting instead of JSON

Comment: Stop console logging everything! Your first `.then()` returns a promise resolving with `undefined`. You should have `.then((res) => res.json())`

Comment: Visting the MusixMatch URL directly, I get a JSON response. Using your CORS proxy URL, I get an HTML page. I think you messed up your CORS proxy deployment

Comment: Its not supposed to be in html, I'm expecting a json file,maybe my cors deployment was the cause,I'll check it quickly

Comment: I console logged to troubleshoot ,my bad , but apart from the cors proxy deployment, what could be the a potential cause?

Comment: Nothing, that is literally your problem. Whatever app you've deployed to Heroku is serving a React app (titled _"Lyrically Demo"_). It is most certainly not acting as a CORS proxy

Comment: the cors was the isuue, thank you @Phil

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert the response to either json or a text format. Then you can able to access the data. Use this

```
.then(res => res.text())
```

Comment: I doubt very much that OP wants or expects an HTML response

Comment: I dont ,its suppose to be a json file

Answer (score -1):

The URL you are using for the fetch argument is wrong. Change

```
`https://corsproxylyricallydemo.herokuapp.com/https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/artist.get?artist_id=118&apikey=${ApiKey}`
```

to

```
`https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/artist.get?artist_id=118&apikey=${ApiKey}`
```

Comment: OP specifically said _"I also created a cors proxy to fix the cors error I was getting earlier"_. The API does not support CORS access